# Instalación de postgresql en una partición de disco diferente al OS

Tags: base-de-datos, ubuntu, postgresql-10

Tengo un servidor con linux Ubuntu 18.04 LTS y deseo instalar postgresql, normalmente lo instalo en la misma partición donde se encuentra el OS pero en este caso deseo instalar postgreSQL en una partición diferente destinada únicamente para la base de datos.

La duda que tengo es que no se como hacer eso ya que los pasos de instalación son básicos y no veo por ningún lado como hacerlo.

#Los pasos que uso actualmente para la instalación son estos

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install postgresql postgresql-contrib
```

Comment: Acá hay una pregunta sin responder que posiblemente aclare tu objetivo: la idea es mover los binarios o la data de la BD? Una cosa es mover los ejecutables (pg_dump, psql, etc) y otra, muy diferente, es decirle que cree los archivos con tus datos de tablas y demás, es otra ubicación. Con lo que ejecutas, dejas todo por defecto pero lo que pides, sin saber el alcance, cambia bastante de una opción a la otra

Comment: Gracias por tu pronta respuesta, mi idea es que todo quede instalado en la otra partición es decir que en la del OS solo quede el OS con sus actualizaciones y demás y que tanto los binarios como los ejecutables y todo lo relacionado con la base de datos quede en la otra partición. Ahora no se si esto sea posible o cual sea la mejor opción.

Answer (score 1):

Alguien ya ha tenido la misma pregunta [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55499184/postgresql-how-can-install-it-in-a-different-location-in-a-linux-server) está una solución,